# Need help making an event do something on click and other event do nothing on click

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar

```
<FullCalendar
                    allDaySlot={true}
                    eventClick={(info) => this.openReservationInfoModal(info.event)}
                    events={[...milestones.map(milestone => ({
                        id: milestone.id,
                        title: milestone.description,
                        start: milestone.expectedDate,
                        allDay: true
                    })), ...this.state.reservations]}
```

what this code do is show in the calendar the milestones and the room reservations but my problem is that in the calendar when I click the reserved room it shows who reserved the room and the reason why it was reserved, only because of this code: `eventClick={(info) => this.openReservationInfoModal(info.event)}` and thats what its suposed to do ; but when I click the milestone on the calendar it shows the same thing it shows when I click the reserved room, What I want is to change the code so that when I click the milestone on the calendar it shows nothing as if it was `eventClick={null}` but when I click the reserved room it still shows who reserved the room and the reason why it was reserved, basically I want to separate the reservations eventClick from the milestones eventClick.

I asked chatgpt and it did this:

```
<FullCalendar
  allDaySlot={true}
  eventClick={(info) => this.handleEventClick(info.event)}
  events={[...milestones.map(milestone => ({
    id: milestone.id,
    title: milestone.description,
    start: milestone.expectedDate,
    allDay: true,
    type: 'milestone' // Add a type property to differentiate milestones
  })), ...this.state.reservations]}
/>

// Event click handler
handleEventClick(event) {
  if (event.extendedProps && event.extendedProps.type === 'milestone') {
    // Handle click for milestones (do nothing or show a different modal)
    // For example, you can add a specific action or leave it empty
    console.log('Milestone clicked');
  } else {
    // Handle click for reservations
    this.openReservationInfoModal(event);
  }
}

// Method to open reservation info modal
openReservationInfoModal(reservation) {
  // Add your logic to show reservation information
  console.log('Reservation clicked', reservation);
  // Display the modal with reservation information
}
```

but it still didnt work

Comment: _"didnt work"_ does not work for us, as a problem description. (Especially not, when we get only shown code fragments, and not a proper [mre].) So what have you done to try and _debug_ this so far? Starting with a console.log of `event.extendedProps` might perhaps be a good idea.

Comment: ... which will probably come back empty here, I think - because you are supposed to add extended properties below the `extendedProps` property, instead of on the top level, according to https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object#non-standard-fields

Comment: @CBroe if you don't though, fullCalendar will just pop them into extendedProps anyway (per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Answer:

```
<FullCalendar
  allDaySlot={true}
  eventClick={(info) => this.handleEventClick(info)}
  events={[...milestones.map(milestone => ({
    id: milestone.id,
    title: milestone.description,
    start: milestone.expectedDate,
    allDay: true,
    type: 'milestone',
  })), ...this.state.reservations]}
/>

// ...

handleEventClick(info) {
  const { event } = info;

  if (event.extendedProps && event.extendedProps.type === 'milestone') {
    // Clicked on a milestone, do nothing or add your custom behavior
    console.log('Clicked on a milestone');
  } else if (event.type !== 'milestone') {
    // Clicked on a reservation, open the reservation info modal
    this.openReservationInfoModal(event);
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be functionally no different than the version in your question. All you've done, as far as I can see, is use `else if` instead of `else` - but that's _more_ restrictive, not less, and should make no difference because anything that isn't a milestone would have gone into the `else` anyway. However since in your original post you didnt clarify what "not working" actually meant in practical terms, it's difficult to be sure what other issue may have been occuring which could have played a part in the problem. This "fix" you've provided here looks suspiciously coincidental, to me.

Comment: @ADyson Why are you complaining about the right answer for my problem???

Comment: My first comment is already explaining why. Did you not understand my point?

Comment: You don't need `else if (event.type !== 'milestone')`, just `else` is fine. What you _do_ need is `handleEventClick(info) {
  const { event } = info;`. You should always _explain_ your answer, instead of just dumping the code, then it's clear to everyone what you changed, and why.

Comment: I admit I focused on the `else` bit, and didn't immediately notice the other change. Hence why you should tell people what you've done!

Answer (score 0):

```
handleEventClick(info) {
```

is needed, compared to the code supplied by chatGPT, because the event object is a sub-property of the argument passed to the handleEventClick callback (as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)

For the same reason

```
if (event.extendedProps && event.extendedProps.type === 'milestone') {
```

needs to be changed to

```
if (info.event.extendedProps && info.event.extendedProps.type === 'milestone') {
```

Fully revised function code:

```
handleEventClick(info) {

  if (info.event.extendedProps && info.event.extendedProps.type === 'milestone') {
    // Clicked on a milestone, do nothing or add your custom behavior
    console.log('Clicked on a milestone');
  } else
    // Clicked on a reservation, open the reservation info modal
    this.openReservationInfoModal(event);
  }
}
```

Live demo (using vanilla JS rather than React, but the handleEventClick function can be written the same way in both): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/vYPmjRp